# K8s Kops 1/3 Master nodes always turn into Not Ready & kube-apiserver pod of that node abnormally restarts frequently

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

Our production KOPS Kubernetes v1.20 deployed in AWS is unhealthy. Intermittently, 1 of the 3 master nodes we have is frequently going into `Not Ready` Status. Furthermore, the kube-apiserver pod is restarting abnormally (in 1hr, 50 restarts). The other 2 master nodes works properly. Sometimes when I run `kubectl get cs` one of the etcd goes into `Unhealthy` state with `HTTP error 503`. It is same output as running `kubectl get --raw='/readyz?verbose'` or `kubectl get --raw='/livez?verbose'`. Sometimes these commands are all healthy, sometimes etcd is not.

Also, the previous log of the problematic kube-apiserver pod running on the problematic master node displays `etcd failed: error getting data from etcd: context deadline exceeded`.

Our business is still operational but I'm afraid our 2 working master node might not cope up in the future if we increase our workload which might result into another failing master.

Comment: It's difficult to help without details. Are you using EKS or deployed manually on EC2? Are there additional log entries that could help? If this is a production issue AWS Support tends to be very helpful, and can be cheaper than downtime.

Comment: Hi @Tim, I am not using EKS. I am using KOPS.  Sometime when I do `kubectl describe master-node-1`, all Messages under Conditions are written as `Kubelet stopped posting node status`. Sometimes, describing the node is alright. This is definitely an intermittent issue

Comment: Hi @Tim, another logs I can give you is when running `journalctl -u kubelet`, most of the logs says, node "ip-<xx-xx-yy-yy>.ec2.internal" not found

Comment: I don't know anything about kops. Good luck.

Comment: Gotcha! @Tim, there is a deprecated kubernetes api service when I run `kubectl get apiservice`. I just use `kubectl delete <apiservice>` then restart my master node.